# Add delete item button - ToDo App - Dart

Tags: dart

I'm very new to dart, so don't judge me. :))

I just started to write a simple ToDo App in Dart. I want to add a button to the item, so i can delete it from the list. I add the button successfully, but don't get the click event working.

I know why the code isn't working, but don't know, what the best solution would be to solve this.

Some improvements would be awesome.

Thanks in advance
Ron

[my little sexy dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/5a1f2aab7d9f52fc2368)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the `onClick` listen to remove the current item on every button. Here's a working version of your code.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

InputElement toDoInput;
UListElement toDoList;

void main() {
  toDoInput = querySelector('#to-do-input');
  toDoList = querySelector('#to-do-list');

  toDoInput.onChange.listen(addToDoItem);
}

// Add item to list
void addToDoItem(Event e) {
  final toDoItem = new LIElement();
  toDoItem.text = toDoInput.value;

  final deleteItemButton = new ButtonElement()
    ..text = 'Delete'
    ..onClick.listen((_) => toDoItem.remove());

  toDoItem.children.add(deleteItemButton);
  toDoList.children.add(toDoItem);

  toDoInput.value = '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense for me! :) Can you tell me the meaning of the underscore in `listen((_) =>`?

Comment: It's the name of the parameter of the function. Usually you use `_` when you don't really need to use the parameter and you want to improve readibility of your code.

Comment: Ah, so no special meaning. thought so. :) Thanks for your help Alex :)